# Insert Reverse Pose Pasting Flips Everything

Tags: rigging

I'm working on a simple walk cycle but when I hit Ctr+C on pose I want inverted and then Ctrl+Shift+V it throws the characters arms up towards the sky and flips the joints of the knees backwards like a flamingo. Giving it the appearance of falling backwards instead of walking forward. Is there some way to get this fixed?

Comment: I have all the bones named opposite i.e upperArm.L and upperArm.R for the life of me i can not figure out why it would do such a thing